# create a new column based on conditional testing of regex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

New to Python & Pandas.

I want to test if a string is in the column and create a new column if condition is satisfied with the string value.

For e.g.

I have a df :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foodstuff':['apple-martini', 'apple-pie', 'lemon-merengue', 'strawberry-tart'], 'type':['cocktail', 'dessert', 'dessert', 'dessert']})
```

and I have two regex strings:

```
fruit = "apple|mango|banana|peach"

recipe = "cocktail|dessert|appetizer"
```

I want to meet the following conditions:

```
df['foodstuff'].str.contains(fruit, case = False) & (df['type'].str.contains(recipe, case = False))
```

In this case, the output would look like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'foodstuff':['apple-martini', 'apple-pie', 'lemon-merengue', 'strawberry-tart'], 'type':['cocktail', 'dessert', 'dessert', 'dessert'], 'tag':['apple', 'apple', np.nan, np.nan ]})
```

I was trying to do it like this:

```
df['tag'] = np.where(df['foodstuff'].str.contains(fruit), fruit, np.nan)
```

but in that case, the 'tag' column takes the entire string value: 
`apple|mango|banana|peach` . I need just the part that matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
fruit = "apple|mango|banana|peach"
df['tag'] = df.foodstuff.str.extract('('+fruit+')', expand=False)
print (df)
         foodstuff      type    tag
0    apple-martini  cocktail  apple
1        apple-pie   dessert  apple
2   lemon-merengue   dessert    NaN
3  strawberry-tart   dessert    NaN
```

Comment: I am not regex expert, but  need capture groups , so need add `()` for `str.extract('(apple|mango|banana|peach)', expand=False)`

Comment: You can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings)

Comment: and `str.extract('(apple|mango|banana|peach)', expand=False)` means extract `apple` or `mango` or `banana` or `peach` and return `Series` obviously.

Comment: Actually I realized that I had to fulfill two conditions - one with contains and the other with the extract . Is there anyway to have both conditions met and do the extract? These are the two conditions: `df['foodstuff'].str.contains(fruit, case = False) & (df['type'].str.contains(recipe, case = False))
`

Comment: Yes, I think you can use two conditons with no problems.

Comment: I'm fumbling on the syntax . . . `df['foodstuff'].str.contains(fruit, case = False) & (df['type'].str.extract(recipe, case = False))` ?

Comment: Yes, but it seems last  `()` can be removed -  `df['foodstuff'].str.contains(fruit, case = False) & df['type'].str.extract(recipe, case = False)`

Comment: it returns a boolean series . . . so I get a new column which has the True / False values instead of the value from the part of the regex which matched . . .

Comment: sorry, `df[df['foodstuff'].str.contains(fruit, case = False) & df['type'].str.extract(recipe, case = False)]`

Comment: Heh heh . . that just subsets the df for the conditions met but does not return the extracted value from the regex.

Comment: I found typo - need `contains` twice - `df[df['foodstuff'].str.contains(fruit, case = False) & df['type'].str.contains(recipe, case = False)]`

Comment: the code above just subsets the existing dataframe  . It does not create a new column with the matched part of the regex !

Comment: anyway - i think this does it: `df['tag'] = df[df['foodstuff'].str.contains(fruit, case = False) & df['type'].str.contains(recipe, case = False)].foodstuff.str.extract('('+fruit+')', expand = False)`

Comment: sorry, for me it was not clear what need exactly. small present +3